# Css: Cambiar color de letra

Tags: css, css3

Estoy intentando realizar el cambio de color de una palabra en el cual recibo ej.:
"EDU MOLA" y las 2 últimas letras de la palabra que sea deben ir en rojo.

```css
.molon:last-letter {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
 <p class='molon'> EDU MOLA </p>
```

La cuestión es que ese last-letter no funciona (Y en el caso de que lo haría pintaría la A no las 2 últimas).
He probado con:

```
.molon:last-child{
```

El problema aquí es que pinta toda la palabra.

La dificultad radica en que este texto será insertado en html mediante un "grid":

```
{
  "name": "descripcion",
  "index": "descripcion",
  "align": "left"
}
```

Por lo que yo no genero el html... así que las soluciones de

`<p class='molon'> EDU MO<span color_rojo>LA </span></p>`

Lo siento pero no valen.
Estaba practicando a ver como obtener las 2 últimas letras con css pero como comenté al principio me está dando problemas.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Esto es un poco bruto, pero puede dar el pego:

```css
.molon::after {
  color: red;
  content: 'LA';
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}
```

```html
 <p class='molon'>EDU MOLA</p>
```

Básicamente lo que hace es superponer el `content` en la misma posición donde esta el texto. Entiendo que en el snippet funciona pero no estoy muy seguro que lo consigas alli donde quieras ponerlo realmente.

Comment: El problema es que puede llegar 2 tipos de palabras finales: ON OFF, si sigo tu ejemplo tendría que crearme 2 clases y aplicar esos estilos si contienen esa palabra, todo esto en el grid, probaré a ver qué tal sale, gracias.